# What should I do about comments which should be an answer, contain misinformation and get a fair number of upvotes?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Specifically I'm referring to the first comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895599/insert-an-element-at-specific-index-in-a-list-and-return-updated-list):

> `b = a[:].insert(2,3)` seems pretty short, doesn't affect the original list and is pretty descriptive.

This comment suggest a solution to the problem and hence it should have been posted as an answer. The real concern however is that this suggestion is plain wrong, yet the comment received 11 upvotes during the last six years. If it was an answer it could also be downvoted and I bet it would score highly negative then. However as it stands, all a new user sees is the 11 upvotes. Most users will likely spot the fallacy of the suggestion and move on, but some might get tricked by it.

I often observe that short answers get posted as comments, but especially the combination of misinformation and upvotes asks for intervention i.m.o. So I flagged the comment for moderator attention and described the problem. Apparently my flag has been handled, but the comment is still there, so it seems the moderator's opinion was different. Hence I'm asking here for advice on what to do in such situations. I'm also interested in opinions on the general answer-as-a-comment policy (regardless of upvotes / quality of information).

Comment: Do not flag comments for moderator attention because they are incorrect. That is not a valid use of comment flags. Moderators do not assess technical correctness.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not just about the technical correctness of the proposed solution, it's also about the fact that a comment clearly attempts to answer the question and thus doesn't belong into the comments section (though opinions seem to differ based on the linked questions). We have a flag for "this answer should be a comment" so to me it appeared natural to also flag for "this comment should be an answer" (regardless of the quality of its content). So do you suggest to not flag these comments, even if they clearly attempt to answer the question (in the end there's probably too many of them).

Comment: No, that is not an appropriate usage of comment flags, either. Moderators cannot convert comments into answers. All that can happen when you flag a comment is the comment gets deleted. We do not delete comments that attempt to answer the question, because that is discarding potentially valuable information.

Comment: @CodyGray That makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: IIRC, the only way to make that comment an answer would be to ask the user to do so. If you want him to delete the comment because it is wrong, then you can simply ping him, saying his comment is techincally incorrect.